# Como renderizo datos de un objeto de la API?

Tags: array, reactjs, api, objeto, jsx

Estoy consultando una api que me devuelve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estoy renderizando los primeros datos de esta manera

```
{!season[0]?.episodeOrder ? 'No episodes' : <p>Episodes: {season[0].episodeOrder}</p>}
{!season[0]?.summary ? 'No summary' : <p>{season[0].summary}</p>}
```

Lo que pretendo es hacer esto para todo el array, intente utilizar un map, pero no funciono.
Agradecería que me dieran ideas de cómo puedo lograr esto.

Comment: Dejame ver si entendi, lo que quieres hacer es mapear cada valor del arreglo en una etiqueta P diferente ? De modo que cada valor del arreglo quede <p>season[0].episodeOrder</p> <p>season[1].episodeOrder</p> <p>season[2].episodeOrder</p> asi sucesivamente?

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si lo que quieres es iterar todos los elementos y mostrarlos en una lista o algo parecido, de momento te dejo este pequeño ejemplo de como los puedes iterar con map, si no es lo que estas buscando házmelo saber, para que modifique la respuesta.

```
//Declaramos un state
const [datos, setDatos] = useState([])
```

Esta parte seria tu fetch donde haces la llamada y supongo que igual estarías renderizando con useEffect en caso de que no esa parte te tocaría a ti agregarla.

```
 fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setItems(result);
         })
```

ahora en el return harias lo siguiente, con map llamas al estado que guardo los datos de la api y solo mandas a llamar cada uno de los datos que quieres mostrar

```
return(
    <ul>
    {datos.map(item => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        {item.episodeOrder} {item.summary}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
  )
```

con esto te dara la lista de todos los valores de la llamada que estas realizando.